# EventListener not working JavaScript and I don't know why

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class `.red` and remove a class `.miniSquare` once you click on a `div` with the class of `.miniSquare`. Unfortunetly when I click on each of the `div`s nothing happens.

Here are the classes (in case you were wondering)

```
 .grid{
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   background-color: green;
 }

.miniSquare {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin: 3px
 }

.red{
background-color: red;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin: 3px
}
```

Here is the JS code:

```
const miniSquares = document.querySelector(".miniSquare");

miniSquares.addEventListener("click", function(){
 this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
 this.setAttribute("class", "red");
});
```

**The Following Is Extra Stuff In Case You Wanted To See**

**Full JS Code**

```
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  let squares = [];

  function createBoad(){
    for (let i = 0; i<100; i++){
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.setAttribute("id", i);
    square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
    grid.appendChild(square);
    squares.push(square);
      }
    }

  createBoad()

  const miniSquares = document.querySelector(".miniSquare");
  miniSquares.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
  this.setAttribute("class", "red");
  });
```

**This is how it looks**
[image]

**Full Code (You have the full code already but this includes the HTML)**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {


const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
let squares = [];

function createBoad(){
  for (let i = 0; i<100; i++){
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.setAttribute("id", i);
    square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
    grid.appendChild(square);
    squares.push(square);
  }
}

createBoad()

const miniSquares = document.querySelector(".miniSquare");
miniSquares.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
  this.setAttribute("class", "red");
});




});
```

```css
.grid{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.miniSquare {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3px
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 3px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bitcoin Mining</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="grid">

</div>


<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating the square object you must add the listener to this object

```js
  function createBoad(){
    for (let i = 0; i<100; i++){
    const square =      document.createElement('div');
    square.setAttribute("id", i);
    square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
    grid.appendChild(square);
    squares.push(square);
      }
    }
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {


const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
let squares = [];

function createBoad(){
  for (let i = 0; i<100; i++){
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.setAttribute("id", i);
    square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
    square.addEventListener("click", function(){
       this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
      this.setAttribute("class", "red");
    });
    grid.appendChild(square);
    squares.push(square);
  }
}

createBoad()

   




});
```

```css
.grid{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.miniSquare {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3px
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 3px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bitcoin Mining</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="grid">

</div>


<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select the div's before you create them: Here's the changed code.

```
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
let squares = [];

function createBoad() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.setAttribute("id", i);
    square.setAttribute("class", "miniSquare");
    grid.appendChild(square);
    squares.push(square);
  }
  const miniSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".miniSquare");
  miniSquares.forEach((item) =>
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
      this.setAttribute("class", "red");
    })
  );
}

createBoad();
```

Comment: That's not true. He was creating and then fetching. The problem was only fetching the first one.

Answer (score 0):

i do this code and its work so when click to the class it changed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>

.miniSquare {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin: 3px
 }

.red{
background-color: red;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin: 3px
}
</style>


<div class="miniSquare">hello.</div>



<script>

const miniSquares = document.querySelector(".miniSquare");

miniSquares.addEventListener("click", function(){
 this.classList.remove("miniSquare");
 this.setAttribute("class", "red");
});

myFunction();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```